# How to handle superfluous response.WriteHeader call in order to return 500

Tags: go

I am aware that the `WriteHeader` method of [http.ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) can only be called once per HTTP response, can only have a single response status code and can only send the headers once. This is all perfectly fine.

The question is, how should I refactor my code in order to override `201` and return `500` if `http.ResponseWriter.Write` returns an error? As you can see below I force panic on purpose to see how [httprouter.Router.PanicHandler](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/blob/master/router.go#L161) handles it. As expected, logs show `http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from ...` and the response is `201` because it is too late as explained above.

```golang
package server

import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func Serve() {
    rtr := httprouter.New()
    rtr.GET("/", home.Welcome)

    handle500(rtr)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", rtr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server crash")
    }
}

func handle500(r *httprouter.Router) {
    r.PanicHandler = func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, err interface{}) {
        res.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        // http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from line above
    }
}
```

```golang
package home

import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
)

func Welcome(res http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    // doing a few bits and building the body

    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    res.WriteHeader(201)

    _, err := res.Write("body goes here")
    if err == nil {  // I am doing this deliberately to test 500
        panic("assume that something has gone wrong with res.Write and an error occurred")
    }
}
```

Comment: Either ignore errors when writing to the response or simply return from the handler.  Is there’s an error writing to the response, then the 500 handler will also fail when writing the response.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no way to "override" the status code as it's sent to the browser immediately.

You're checking for the return value of `http.ResponseWriter.Write()`. I'm not sure this is a good strategy. If writing the response failed then chances are that writing more will probably fail, too.

Logging the failure seems more appropriate, but I would expect most failures to be dropped connections and other errors which won't require action.

Comment: I found this answer looking for another issue. FYI [at least as of Go 1.17](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/net/http/server.go;l=120-126), `http.ResponseWriter.Write` implicitly calls `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` whether that's what you want or not. Therefore, you _must_ manually call `w.WriteHeader` _before_ anything writes to the response to set HTTP codes manually.