# Why do I get this error/warning related to writing a response header?

Tags: go, web, server

I get this error, regardless of which way round I set the content type and write the status code. I can't really figure out why...

It seems to me like a very mundane task - I just want to set the Content-Type and the http status code. The server does actually work, it serves the web page just fine, but it logs that message to the terminal every time I request that endpoint/path.

**Error**

```
http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.indexHandler (server.go:49)
```

**Code**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fs))

    r.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler).Methods("GET")

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    "0.0.0.0:8080",
        Handler: r,
    }

    go func() {
        if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Unable to start the server")
        }
    }()

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    <-c

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    if err := server.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to gracefully shutdown the server")
    }
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/index.html")
}
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828645/how-to-handle-superfluous-response-writeheader-call-in-order-to-return-500 help? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906490/whats-the-bad-effect-of-http-multiple-response-writeheader-calls ?

Comment: It doesn’t unfortunately. I don’t see where I could be writing multiple headers - though clearly I’m missing part of the picture.

Comment: I've added an answer for the specific question in your comment, but the links provided above are still useful background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/index.html")
}
```

You don't need the `w.WriteHeader` call. `http.ServeFile` will set the status based on its success in serving the file.

If you want to understand how this error message comes to be, look at the implementation of the `WriteHeader` method and what it does if the header is already written.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense. Thanks. I can see in "fs.go" at line 297 it does indeed set the status code by calling "WriteHeader(code)".

Comment: @SamWood: yes, and the code has a clever `relevantCaller` function that does some stack walking to find where the actual culprit is

Comment: Actually the inverse is true, the `WriteHeader` sends the header which can’t be overwritten, and the `ServeFile` header becomes superfluous, meaning that it won’t be able to indicate any status other than 200

Comment: @JimB: thanks for the comment, you're right. I removed the confusing sentence from my answer.